# How to draw a curve passing through a set of 2D points using Core Plot library for iOS?

Tags: ios, core-plot

Can anyone point me to an example that uses core plot library to draw a curve through N Points as a graph ?

IMPORTANT : I have used core-plot. Unfortunately it just joins your dots with straight lines and not smooth curves.

For achieving this we need to use this method.
the code is in C# to generate control points for a bezier spline.
I converted this code to Objective C and it works brilliantly for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx

Make sure that all the arrays used in the code are filled with 'n' NSNull objects as the C# code here uses dynamic arrays where we can put values at any index but same cant be done in Objective C unless we have the existing index in the NSMutableArrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [Google Search](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Core%20Plot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ySQ&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&source=hp&q=core%20plot%20tutorial&oq=Core%20Plot%20tuto&aq=0&aqi=g3g-m1g-b3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1990l3242l0l4353l5l5l0l0l0l0l339l1483l0.1.0.4l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=bdeb326aa44b07c5&biw=1920&bih=956) i did

Here is the Core-Plot's Own example project: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples)

And a Third party Tutorial: [Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)

Also here is a helpful snippet from the Core-Plot Developers: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications)

Hope it helps, btw most people on here will prob tell you to use Google for a simple request like this.

So for future reference when you need an example of an API search in google the following "Insert API Name here" Tutorial, This will usually return at least 1 tutorial in most cases on the first page

Comment: The point is I was looking for exactly the thing I wanted thats why I asked.
Core Plot seemed to have so many things that I was wondering, whether it has the basic feature I want.
Thanks a lot for the references but I actually got the things from Google search myself and while looking at examples I found what I wanted before looking at this answer.
Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Please see the important note I have given in the edited question.